# PHP toggle button that keeps the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

After lurking for some years, I've finally created a user.

I'll try to explain my problem to you as good as I can:

I need a small browser friendly document (HTML, PHP, whatever) that enables me and a few colleagues to flip a switch so we can see if any drove to work. 
I can create the switch, and it works fine - however, I need it to keep it's state, spanning on several computers, and I was wondering if that is possible without making a DB?

I'd love to keep it simple, and in one file.

Example:

Dude1 comes to work, cycling. Switch is OFF

Dude2 comes to work, walking. Switch is OFF

Dude3 comes to work, driving. Switch is ON

--

Dude1 wants to see who's driving today. Opens the PHP/HTML and can see the status:

Dude1 - OFF

Dude2 - OFF

Dude3 - ON

---

I hope that explains my problem, if not please ask and I'll try to be clearer.

```
 <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="switch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="switch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

That was the easy part - now how to keep the state.

---

Edit, added a picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7zjr.png)

Comment: you need to post the variables, put everything inside a form with an action to a php script that either inserts the data into a database or stores it as a `$_SESSION` (the latter is not recommended)

Comment: Should every colleague be able to access the application from their devices or is there a shared/public station everyone uses for this purpose? What is the reason you don't want to use a database? Is a file-based database such as SQLite acceptable?

Comment: @simlev It should be accessable from their workstation/devices on the internal network.
SQLite would be acceptable, although I don't know much about it - what is the requirements? The reason for not using a DB in the first place, was to make it as "small" as possible, like having a single PHP-file on a server, so they just had to navigate to server/file.php or 10.10.10.10/file.php

Comment: Then I'd recommend using a database, since it allows for greater flexibility at the "cost" of having an additional file other than your `file.php`. Requirements for SQLite are a writable file and the php sqlite extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bro, to save state you have the following methods

**Client Side**

1. LocalStorage
2. SessionStorage

**Server Side**

1. Session

**Application wide**

1. DB
2. File

Client Side & Server Side only works with in a computer. If you want to maintain in different computers then you have to go with DB or File.

Comment: So there is no "easy fix" for this? I have to create a DB and write the state of the switch, and then read it again?
And if so - how do I do that, without making 10+ entries each day?

Comment: You would only write an entry for each colleague that drove to work; is that too much? Why?

Comment: if you don't want to use DB.  Just write to a file. Override the entry after each colleague change the status.        https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fwrite.asp

Comment: @simlev 
Wouldn't it write an entry for each click, or would it overwrite?

Comment: @imranahmed
Thanks, I'll look into that link.

Comment: @j.andreasen Your comments are in the database design domain. You could have a record for each user that defaults to "off" or only write a "on" record for those users who drove to work and assume the rest has "off". You could even only maintain a single record with a column for each user as imran ahmed seems to suggest in his comment. You could choose to add a "date" column and keep history or truncate the table everyday and start anew or reset the values at the beginning of each day and just keep overwriting them.

Comment: @j.andreasen I'd keep two tables in the database: one with the employees's names (and possibly other details), the other with their name or id, date and means of transport for that day. I'd then show an icon next to the name showing e.g. a bicycle, a car, a bus...It really boils down to a matter of personal taste and goals that you want to achieve, but having a database allows for greater flexibility and more easily adding features later.

Comment: @simlev (and others)
(I hate that you cant press enter here - oh well xD)
I decided to create a DB instead, being the only real solution to my problem. Thanks for all your help :) Don't think that it's the last time that I'll use Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do that without any database. The simplest one I can think of is using [HTML5 Local Storage](http://%3Ca%20href=%22https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage%22%3E%3C/a%3E).

With this, you can manage to keep some data related to a specific website in the browser. Data is stored in JSON format, which apparently means you will be needing a key and a value.

Setting the value -

```
localStorage.setItem('driving', 'Yes');
```

Javascript to set the value of checkbox -

```
if (localStorage.getItem('driving')=='Yes'){
    //code to set your checkbox
}
```

For more checkout [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without a Database. Simple as that.

If you want to reduce the DB entries, you can keep a table with following fields:

id, name, status, date_modified

if a colleague turns on the switch for today, just update the status and date for that colleague

while displaying the list (for today), the rows having today's date will have the status as per the database, rest all will have the switch turned off

Comment: I did almost exactly what you wrote - but I'm having issues extracting the data from the date_modified row of the SQL? I used the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to update the rows - but when I try to extract it, it ends up blank? Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid me - a simple typo. It works (almost) perfectly now. Thanks.

Comment: @j.andreasen - sorry! I gave the answer but forgot to reply to the follow-up questions. Glad to hear it is working. You're welcome!